# How to set path that contains spaces in a YAML file in a GitHub workflow?

Tags: bash, docker, yaml, latex, github-actions

I have a repository that has a LaTex file inside a folder. The folder is named `Literature Review` and the file is named `Review.tex`. I'm new to docker and GitHub Actions. I have tried a lot of different combinations to set the file path:

`Literature Review/Review.tex`

I have tried a lot of methods suggested on StackOverflow but it seems I'm too naive to understand the implementation correctly xD

I read somewhere that to avoid an escape sequence, we can use a `\` before the space. This, however, did not make much difference.

The workflow returns the following error while building:

```
Run echo ${MANUSCRIPT_PATH}.tex
  echo ${MANUSCRIPT_PATH}.tex
  ${LATEX} ${MANUSCRIPT_PATH}.tex
  ${BIBTEX} ${MANUSCRIPT_PATH}.aux
  ${LATEX} ${MANUSCRIPT_PATH}.tex
  ${LATEX} ${MANUSCRIPT_PATH}.tex
  shell: /bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    MANUSCRIPT_PATH: Literature\ Review/Review
    LATEX: pdflatex -shell-escape
    BIBTEX: bibtex
Literature\ Review/Review.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `Literature'.
<to be read again> 
                   \ 
<*> Literature\ 
                Review/Review.tex
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<to be read again> 
                   \ 
<*> Literature\ 
                Review/Review.tex
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on texput.log.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

My `yml` file looks like this:

```
name: paper-maker

on: push

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      # This needs fixing
      MANUSCRIPT_PATH: 'Literature\ Review/Review' # exclude the '.tex' / '.pdf' extension!
      LATEX: pdflatex -shell-escape
      BIBTEX: bibtex
    steps: 
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Install texlive
      run: |
        sudo apt-get install texlive-publishers \
                             texlive-latex-recommended \
                             texlive-latex-extra \
                             texlive-fonts-recommended \
                             texlive-fonts-extra
    - name: Build paper
      run: |
        echo ${MANUSCRIPT_PATH}.tex
        ${LATEX} ${MANUSCRIPT_PATH}.tex
        ${BIBTEX} ${MANUSCRIPT_PATH}.aux
        ${LATEX} ${MANUSCRIPT_PATH}.tex
        ${LATEX} ${MANUSCRIPT_PATH}.tex
    - name: Push paper
      run: |
        git checkout --orphan ${GITHUB_REF##*/}-pdf
        git rm -rf .github/
        git rm -rf . 
        git add -f ${MANUSCRIPT_PATH##*/}.pdf
        git -c user.name='paper-maker' -c user.email='paper-maker' commit -m "update pdf"
        git push -q -f https://${{ github.actor }}:${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}@github.com/${{ github.repository }} ${GITHUB_REF##*/}-pdf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't try to individually escape space characters, just put the resulting path in double quotes:

```yaml
MANUSCRIPT_PATH: Literature Review/Review
```

```sh
${LATEX} "${MANUSCRIPT_PATH}.tex"
${BIBTEX} "${MANUSCRIPT_PATH}.aux"
${LATEX} "${MANUSCRIPT_PATH}.tex"
${LATEX} "${MANUSCRIPT_PATH}.tex"
```

It seems that backslash-escapes are processed before variable substitution, which is why your approach doesn't work.

In any case, putting the final path in double quotes is long-established best practice.

---

Edit: To elaborate a bit, this has nothing to do with Docker or YAML. Just try this piece of code in bash:

```
mkdir -p a\ b && echo "foo" > a\ b/c.txt
P='a\ b/c' cat $P.txt
```

You will get

```
cat: a\: No such file or directory
cat: b/c.txt: No such file or directory
```

As you can see, the backslash is *not* escaping the following space in variable substitution. Instead, the shell acts like you gave the two parameters `'a\'` and `'b/c.txt'`.

Answer (score 4):

Use double quotation marks inside of the single quotation marks like this: `'"Literature Review/Review"'`. Parsing the YAML removes the single quotation marks and the value of your environment variable will be `"Literature Review/Review"`. This in turn will make pdflatex receive `Literature Review/Review` as a single argument.

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      # fixed
      MANUSCRIPT_PATH_TEX: '"Literature Review/Review.tex"'
[...]
    - name: Build paper
      run: |
        echo ${MANUSCRIPT_PATH_TEX}
        ${LATEX} ${MANUSCRIPT_PATH_TEX}
        ${BIBTEX} ${MANUSCRIPT_PATH_TEX}
        ${LATEX} ${MANUSCRIPT_PATH_TEX}
        ${LATEX} ${MANUSCRIPT_PATH_TEX}
```

Comment: It shows the following error: 
`! Unbalanced quotes in argument "Literature`
`Error: Process completed with exit code 1.`